# Check whether a string is an instance of an enum

Tags: c#

I have the following `enum` declaration:

```
enum MyType
{
   Boolean,
   Int,
   Double,
   String
}
```

Then if I have a `string abc = "anyvalue"`, how can I check whether the `abc` value is either bool, int, double or string corresponding to a `myType` enumerated value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Enum.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx) method. This will return true if the value was successfully parsed into one of the enumeration values while also outputting the parsed enumeration value.

If you want to ignore case when performing the parsing use the overload that accepts a boolean parameter.

```
MyType type;
if (Enum.TryParse(abc, out type))
{
    // can be parsed
    switch (type)
   {
       case MyType.Boolean: break;
       case MyType.Int: break;
       case MyType.Double: break;
       case MyType.String: break;
   }
}
```

It's also possible to use [`Enum.IsDefined`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined.aspx) but this method always does a case-sensitive search so it is less flexible than [`Enum.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991317.aspx) and can only be used to know if the name is defined or not.

Comment: this is only available for .net >4 I think

Comment: Yes, `TryParse` was introduced only in .NET 4.0, however `Parse` and `IsDefined` is supported in previous framework versions and can be used to workaround the lack of `TryParse`. In the future if you have restrictions related to .NET version you should state it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
MyType dummy;
if(bool isEnum = Enum.TryParse(mystring,out dummy))
{
// mystring is a valid enum 
}
```